# Javascript for loop efficiency

Tags: javascript

Is

```
for (var i=0, cols=columns.length; i<cols; i++) { ... }
```

more efficient than

```
for (var i=0; i<columns.length; i++) { ... }
```

?

In the second variant, is `columns.length` calculated each time the condition `i<columns.length` is checked ?

Comment: WARNING:  Make sure cols is declared with **var** and **inside of a function**. Unless both of these are so, JavaScript might treat it as a global variable (and thus make accesses slower).  WebKit-based browsers pretty much ignore var in the global scope, even if the variable in question conflicts with a global variable (like `status`, for instance).

Comment: @Joey Adams: 'var i=0, cols=columns.length` will declare cols as a var, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any expression that's in the second portion of a for will be evaluated once per loop.

So, here, with your second proposition, yes, `columns.length` will be calculated each time the condition is checked -- which would make the first proposition faster than the second one.

*(That's true for many other languages, btw)*

Comment: This doesn't address whether a smart JS runtime could optimize it out.

Comment: Tried it in Chrome and Firefox (both of which currently use dynamic compilation), and in both, caching `columns.length` with a local variable is faster than using `columns.length` in the loop.

Comment: @Joey Adams: Just out of curiosity, how much faster is it? Is this the sort of thing you'd classify as a premature optimization in most cases?

Answer (score 5):

Micro optimizations like this don't make huge sense in a language like Javascript unless you have tested and found the loop performance to be an issue.

However, columns.length must be evaluated on each iteration because the number of columns may change during a loop iteration.  Therefore storing the loop limit may give slightly better performance (but see my first point).

Answer (score 4):

The cached version is faster but, the 2nd version safer.

If you're just curious about which loop types are fastest you may want to check this out: http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.html

Comment: the link is great! answers the question with empirical data.

Answer (score 1):

Note that most of these loops require an additional statement in the loop to actually retrieve the i'th element from the array. You can avoid that and get a very fast loop with the following variant, which takes advantage of the fact that Javascript just returns undefined (which evaluates to false), if you access an array with an out of bounds index (rather than raising an error):

> for (var i = 0, col; col = columns[i]; ++i) { ... }

Obviously this doesn't work if you're iterating through an array which contains elements which would evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Accessing the length property wastes un-needed time (unless the array's length can change during iteration.).