# Adding functions to javascript's Array class breaks for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

I was looking for a way to add max/min functions to JavaScript's Array class, which seemed to be a solved problem: [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values). However, when I tried using that, I started getting errors from my code. It turns out that this approach doesn't work with loops.

```
for(i in myArray) { console.log(i) } 

prints out


1

2 

3

max

min
```

Is there another approach I can use?

Comment: No, i does not. Consider reading on "working with arrays"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for...in` loop is used for looping through properties of an object.  If you want to get the values from your array, you can do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    console.log(myArray[i])
}
```

Comment: also, `object[string]` vs. `array[number]`

Comment: Why not use `i <` like everyone else?

Comment: @missignno - no good reason (that was the way I had it in a local example), doing `i < myArray.length` as you suggest in your answer is actually cleaner, IMO.

Comment: You actually want to use `for (var i = 0, I = myArray.length; i < I; i++)` as this is still faster in most browsers; see https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.html (caching length) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742396/javascript-for-loop-efficiency

Answer (score 10):

The accepted solution solves your immediate problem, but extending core objects is generally a [bad idea](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/). What happens when you include a library later that uses `for..in`? Or when you forget months later and use the wrong approach in a different section of your code?

Another option is to wrap and extend. Create a new type that uses an instance of `Array` as its prototype:

```
function ArrayThing() {}

ArrayThing.prototype = new Array();
```

Now you've got an object that you can extend without affecting `Array`:

```
ArrayThing.prototype.max = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(null, [].slice.call(this, 0))
}

ArrayThing.prototype.min = function() {
    return Math.min.apply(null, [].slice.call(this, 0))
}

var list = new ArrayThing();

// standard array methods still work
list.push(5);
list.push(22);
list.push(0);
list.push(-14);
list.length // => 4

// as do your new custom methods
list.max() // => 22
list.min() // => -14
```

This won't work in every situation, but unless you're sure you really, really need an `Array`, this is a useful alternative.

Answer (score 2):

`for in` is a common Javascript trap. Instead of behaving like a `foreach` from other languages, it actualy enumerates all properties in a given object.

Since Javascript Arrays happen to have a property for each index using `for in` works sometimes, but as you have seen, it also enumerates any other properties you add. Another issue is that the `for in` is not guaranteed to go through the properties in any particular order, so your results can vary depending on which browser/runtime you use.

It is safer, then, to just use a boring `for` loop instead. There are many `for` loop idioms in Javascript, so I will list some:

Regular for loop:

```
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
```

Regular loop, caching the length:

```
for(i=0, n=arr.length; i<n; i++){
```

Loops over arrays of objects/NodeLists:

```
for(i=0; obj=arr[i]; i++){ //this works as long as the array has no falsy values
    foo(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a check using hasOwnProperty. 
However this needs to applied wherever you are looping.

i.e:

```
for(i in myArray)
{
  if(arr.hasOwnProperty(i))
  {
   console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: To me, this is such a hack-around. I refuse to add such code around all my `for in` loops. Therefore, I refuse to allow the use of any libraries that extend JS Object. Also, you shouldn't use `for in` to iterate over arrays if you expect it to be returned in order, the order of elements in `for in` is undefined. It currently works, but most new browsers are dropping that behavior in favor of performance gains

Answer (score 0):

There's a more modern (IE9+) way to do this now:

```
var g = []; 

Object.defineProperty(g, "log", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function(){ console.log(this); }
});


g.push(5); 
g.push(9); 

var t;
for (t in g){
    console.log(g[t]);
}
```

prints 5 and 9 but does not list the "log" function

```
g.log() -> echos [5,9]
```

The key to this working is being able to flag a property as "enumerable: false" with marks the property as something that shouldn't be iterated over.

More on Object.defineProperty here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty