# Javascript: Assigning to Object or Array Prototype Causes Brackets to Not Work

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding functions to javascript's Array class breaks for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020954/adding-functions-to-javascripts-array-class-breaks-for-loops)

Before anyone says anything, I know it's generally bad practice to assign something with Object.prototype, but this is something that I want ALL objects to have if this chunk of code is included. It's also odd that it's happening when I do it with Array as well. This is taking place in Node.js, so it's with the V8 javascript engine. Anyways, here's what's going on. I'm just assigning a function to the prototype of one of these two types (I've tried both individually with the same error as the outcome, and it doesn't happen when I use other types).

```
Array.prototype.test = function() { console.log("test"); }

var a = ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    index,
    entry;

a.test(); //prints 'test'

for(index in a) {
  entry = (a[index]).split("e"); //throws an error
}
```

The error is

```
Object Function () {console.log("test");} has no method 'split'
```

thoughts?

Comment: `for...in` iterates over all properties of an object. So you will eventually access `a['test']`, which is the function you defined. Functions don't have a `.split` method. Read [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) especially the second yellow box).

Answer (score 0):

If you run this, you will see what's going on because you used prototype on array, the function becomes part of the object, and split on that throws the error.

```
Array.prototype.test = function() { console.log("test"); }

var a = ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    index,
    entry;

a.test(); //prints 'test'

for(index in a) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(a);
//  entry = (a[index]).split("e"); //throws an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should iterate that array with:

```
for(index=0;index<a.length;index++)
```

because when you add members they become part of the array, see it better with

```
for(i in a) console.log(i);
```

this will print all the keys plus the function name "test"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
varTest = console.log("test");
Array.prototype.test = function() { varTest }

var a = ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    index,
    entry;

a.test(); //prints 'test'

for(index in a) {
  entry = (a[index]).split("e"); //throws an error
}
```