# Efficient way of filtering arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

Below code takes long lots of minutes;

```
var table = new Array();
for(var i =0; i< dtObjects.Rows.length; i++)
        {
            for(var j=0; j< dtColumns.Rows.length; j++)
            {
                for(var k=0; k< dtTypes.Rows.length; k++)
                {
                  if((dtObjects.Rows[i].Id == dtColumns.Rows[j].Id) && (dtColumns.Rows[j].xtype == dtTypes.Rows[k].xtype))  

                      table.push({
                          TableName : dtObjects.Rows[i].Name,
                          Type:  dtObjects.Rows[i].type,
                          ColumName:  dtColumns.Rows[j].Name,
                          DataType: dtTypes.Rows[k].Name,
                          Length : dtColumns.Rows[j].Length
                      });
                }
            }
        }
```

dtObjects.Rows.length = 900

dtColumns.Rows.length = 1500

dtTypes.Rows.length = 30

Is there anyway to achieve (filter) this in seconds?

Comment: i dont know the answer but i am quite interested in an answer.

Comment: is the relation of the elements count always the same? (`dtTypes.rows.length` < `dtObjects.Rows.length` < `dtColumns.Rows.length`)

Comment: no. lengths are arbitrary.

Comment: I know the answer, but I'm too lazy to prepare sample data, create a fiddle, etc - something you should have done yourself.

Comment: You are using some kind of bubble (sorting). Take a look at other (sorting) algorithms that are probably more efficient for your scenario.
see: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: no sorting. Actually I am doing inner join in inefficient way.

Comment: prepare some sample data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742396/javascript-for-loop-efficiency. Cache your dtObjects.Rows.length in a variable in your `for` loop. Rather than calculating it on every loop like your currently doing. `for(var i=0, len=dbObjects.Rows.length; i<len; i++)`

Comment: you're doing this client side? isn't that like 40.5 million ops?

Comment: is `ID` in `dtColumns.Rows` and `xtype` in `dtTypes.Rows` unique?

Comment: Yes you do, but a bit in an other way. If you would group and sort the objects in the first place then you wouldn't have to iterate through the whole array a second time (2 dimension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With out any sample data we won't able to do much, but in an abstract this is how I might look at a solution

```
var table = new Array();

var dtObjectMap = {}, dtColumnMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < dtObjects.Rows.length; i++) {
    dtObjectMap['id-' + dtObjects.Rows[i].Id] = dtObjects.Rows[i];
}

for (var j = 0; j < dtColumns.Rows.length; j++) {
    if (!dtColumnMap[dtColumns.Rows[j].xtype]) {
        dtColumnMap[dtColumns.Rows[j].xtype] = [];
    }
    dtColumnMap[dtColumns.Rows[j].xtype].push(dtColumns.Rows[j]);
}

var dtObject, dtColumn, dtType, dtCXtypes;
for (var k = 0; k < dtTypes.Rows.length; k++) {
    dtType = dtType.Rows[i], dtCXtypes = dtColumnXtypes[dtType.xtype];
    if (dtCXtypes && dtCXtypes.length) {
        for (var l = 0; l < dtCXtypes.length; l++) {
            dtColumn = dtCXtypes[l];
            dtObject = dtObjectMap['id-' + dtColumn.id];
            if (dtObject) {
                table.push({
                    TableName : dtObject.Name,
                    Type : dtObject.type,
                    ColumName : dtColumn.Name,
                    DataType : dtType.Name,
                    Length : dtColumn.Length
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you did not put a break when your condition matches. there is no need to go continue after matching condition.

You can do one thing. As per your condition `(dtObjects.Rows[i].Id == dtColumns.Rows[j].Id) && (dtColumns.Rows[j].xtype == dtTypes.Rows[k].xtype)` I am telling you this logic.

First loop dtObjects and dtColumns and check for condtion `dtObjects.Rows[i].Id == dtColumns.Rows[j].Id`. Whatever **id's are matching** put that **"j value"** new array (do not forget to put a break when Id match).

Once you done with this loop. Take one more loop for newArray and dtTypes. Check your condition in this manner "`dtColumns[newArray[k]].xtype == dtTypes.Rows[l].xtype`"

One more thing, keep the object as a outer loop who has more count.

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = new Array();
for(var i =0; i< dtObjects.Rows.length; i++)
        {
            for(var j=0; j< dtColumns.Rows.length; j++)
            {
                if(dtObjects.Rows[i].Id == dtColumns.Rows[j].Id){
                    for(var k=0; k< dtTypes.Rows.length; k++)
                {
                  if(dtColumns.Rows[j].xtype == dtTypes.Rows[k].xtype) 

                      table.push({
                          TableName : dtObjects.Rows[i].Name,
                          Type:  dtObjects.Rows[i].type,
                          ColumName:  dtColumns.Rows[j].Name,
                          DataType: dtTypes.Rows[k].Name,
                          Length : dtColumns.Rows[j].Length
                      });
                }

             }

            }
        }
```

I just conditioned your first condition before your last loop this will make it "little bit" faster

Answer (score 1):

First you can sort both dtObjects and dtColums by id:

```
function sortById(a,b){
  return (a.id>b.id)?1:(a.id<b.id)?-1:0;
}
dtOjbects.Rows.sort(sortById);
dtColumns.Rows.sort(sortById);

var table = new Array(),
j=0,i=0,
colLen=dtColumns.Rows.length,
objLen=dtObjects.Rows.length,
typLen=dtTypes.Rows.length,
tmpMatch=[];
for(i =0; i< objLen; i++){
  while(j<colLen||dtObjects.Rows[i].id>dtColumns.Rows[j].id){
    if(dtObjects.Rows[i].id===dtColumns.Rows[j].id){
      tmpMatch.push([i,j]);
    }
    j++;
  }
}
for(i=0;i<tmpMatch.length;i++){
  for(j=0;j<typLen;j++){
    if(dtColumns.Rows[tmpMatch[i][1]].xtype == dtTypes.Rows[j].xtype){
      table.push({
        TableName : dtObjects.Rows[tmpMatch[i][0]].Name,
        Type:  dtObjects.Rows[tmpMatch[i][0]].type,
        ColumName:  dtColumns.Rows[tmpMatch[i][1]].Name,
        DataType: dtTypes.Rows[j].Name,
        Length : dtColumns.Rows[tmpMatch[i][1]].Length
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating index object using Id.

```
var table = new Array(),
    orows = dtObjects.Rows,
    crows = dtColumns.Rows,
    crowsIndex = {},
    types = dtTypes.Rows,
    typesIndex = {};

for (var j = 0; j < crows.length; j++) {
    crowsIndex[crows[j].Id] = crows[j];
}

for (var k = 0; k < types.length; k++) {
    typesIndex[types[k].xtype] = types[k];
}

for (var i = 0; i < orows.length; i++) {
    var rID = orows[i].Id;
    if (crowsIndex[rID]) {
        var xType = crowsIndex[rID].xtype;
        if (typesIndex[xType]) {
            table.push({
                TableName: orows[i].Name,
                Type: orows[i].type,
                ColumName: crowsIndex[rID]].Name,
            DataType: typesIndex[xType].Name,
            Length: crowsIndex[rID].Length
            });
    }
}
```

This is NOT TESTED and may not be the final solution you need, but will help you to get started. Please provide sample data to test.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Arun's answer (albeit maybe simpler).

What you can do if you are willing to trade a little more memory use for increased speed, is creating a hash of the objects that you will be checking against.

Checking existence in a hash is considerably faster that iterating through and comparing Ids for each column, row & type. To take advantage of that you can start by creating a hash of both of the types and the columns collections, then you only have to check for existence within the hash.

```
var table = new Array();
var columnsHash = {};
for(var j=0; j< dtColumns.Rows.length; j++) {
  columnsHash[dtColumns.Rows[j].Id] = dtColumns.Rows[j];
}
var typesHash = {};
for(var k=0; k< dtTypes.Rows.length; k++) {
  typesHash[dtTypes.Rows[k].xtype] = dtTypes.Rows[k];
}

for(var i =0; i< dtObjects.Rows.length; i++) {
  var typesObj, columnObj = columnsHash[dtObjects.Rows[i].Id];
  if (columnObj && (typesObj = typesHash[columnObj.xtype])) {
    table.push({
      TableName : dtObjects.Rows[i].Name,
      Type:  dtObjects.Rows[i].type,
      ColumName:  columnObj.Name,
      DataType: typesObj.Name,
      Length : columnObj.Length
    });
  }
}
```

Note: I haven't actually tested the code, obviously, but in theory this should work, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This will give considerable speed. We need to know how many matching column possible for each row. If it is just one you can break the loop also once matched.

```
var table = new Array();

for(var i =0; i< dtObjects.Rows.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j=0; j< dtColumns.Rows.length; j++)
        {
            if(dtObjects.Rows[i].Id == dtColumns.Rows[j].Id)
            {
                for(var k=0; k< dtTypes.Rows.length; k++)
                {

                    if((dtColumns.Rows[j].xtype == dtTypes.Rows[k].xtype))  {
                          table.push({
                          TableName : dtObjects.Rows[i].Name,
                          Type:  dtObjects.Rows[i].type,
                          ColumName:  dtColumns.Rows[j].Name,
                          DataType: dtTypes.Rows[k].Name,
                          Length : dtColumns.Rows[j].Length
                      });
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```